# change the color of UITableView section title

Tags: ios, core-data

i have TableView with Sections, the sections are Countries and i fetch them from my core data entity. i set a background image for my tableview and now i want to change the title color of the section. how can i do that? here is my code so far.

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];

    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    if (sectionTitle == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(20, 6, 300, 30);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    //label.text = sectionTitle;
    label.text=[sectionInfo name];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width,tableView.bounds.size.height)];

    [view addSubview:label];

    return [sectionInfo name];

}
```

when i try my code i get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return a string (the title) in that method. Check out:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

That is where you should be customizing the look.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of your sections in the UITableView you should use this method from [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```